# Intersecting Triangle and BoundingBox in 3D environment

Tags: libgdx, bounding-boxes, intersection

I am trying to check if a triangle is intersecting a BoundingBox in a 3D space with libgdx, but I am unable to find anything that can help me with that.

I tried using a Plane but it is not precise enough and I would like to avoid using Bullet.

Is there any existing code that I can use to deal with this ?

Comment: A triangle is a 2D shape while a BoundingBox is a 3D shape, do you mean a triangle and a rectangle? Otherwise can you post a picture as an example of what you mean?

Comment: @Charanor On the picture linked below, I use the triangle to represent the floor and the BoundingBox as a the player hitbox and I wanted to know when the 2 intersects.

[i.imgur.com/qE6DJlZ.jpg](http://i.imgur.com/qE6DJlZ.jpg)

Answer (score -2):

```
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //    use separating axis theorem to test overlap 
        //    between triangle and box 
        //    need to test for overlap in these directions: 
        //    1) the {x,y,z}-directions (actually, since we use 
        //       the AABB of the triangle 
        //       we do not even need to test these) 
        //    2) normal of the triangle 
        //    3) crossproduct(edge from tri, {x,y,z}-directin) 
        //       this gives 3x3=9 more tests

        static int TriangleVsAABB2(const glm::vec3 &bmin,
                                   const glm::vec3 &bmax,
                                   const glm::vec3 &boxcenter,
                                   const glm::vec3 &boxhalfsize,
                                   const glm::vec3 &trivert0,
                                   const glm::vec3 &trivert1,
                                   const glm::vec3 &trivert2,
                                   const glm::vec3 &normal)
        {

            // if triangle is entirely inside the bounding box, then exit

            if ((trivert0.x >= bmin.x && trivert0.x <= bmax.x) && (trivert0.y >= bmin.y && trivert0.y <= bmax.y) && (trivert0.z >= bmin.z && trivert0.z <= bmax.z))
                if ((trivert1.x >= bmin.x && trivert1.x <= bmax.x) && (trivert1.y >= bmin.y && trivert1.y <= bmax.y) && (trivert1.z >= bmin.z && trivert1.z <= bmax.z))
                    if ((trivert2.x >= bmin.x && trivert2.x <= bmax.x) && (trivert2.y >= bmin.y && trivert2.y <= bmax.y) && (trivert2.z >= bmin.z && trivert2.z <= bmax.z))
                        return INSIDE;

            // if we get here triangle maybe intersecting the cube or could be totally out

            float d,min,max;
            float p0, p1, p2;
            glm::vec3 fe,vmin,vmax;
            glm::vec3 v0,v1,v2;
            glm::vec3 e0, e1, e2;

            // center at 0,0,0 

            v0 = trivert0 - boxcenter;
            v1 = trivert1 - boxcenter;
            v2 = trivert2 - boxcenter;

            // compute triangle edges 

            e0 = v1 - v0;
            e1 = v2 - v1;
            e2 = v0 - v2;

            //  test the 9 tests for axis overlapping 

            // axis test x01

            fe = glm::abs(e0);

            p0 = e0.z * v0.y - e0.y * v0.z;
            p2 = e0.z * v2.y - e0.y * v2.z;

            min = p2;
            max = p0;

            if (p0<p2)
            {
                min = p0;
                max = p2;
            }

            d = fe.z * boxhalfsize.y + fe.y * boxhalfsize.z;

            if (min>d || max<-d) return OUTSIDE;

            // axis test y02

            p0 = -e0.z * v0.x + e0.x * v0.z;
            p2 = -e0.z * v2.x + e0.x * v2.z;

            min = p2;
            max = p0;

            if (p0<p2) { min = p0; max = p2; }

            d = fe.z * boxhalfsize.x + fe.x * boxhalfsize.z;

            if (min>d || max<-d) return OUTSIDE;

            // axis test z12

            p1 = e0.y * v1.x - e0.x * v1.y;
            p2 = e0.y * v2.x - e0.x * v2.y;

            min = p1;
            max = p2;

            if (p2<p1)
            {
                min = p2;
                max = p1;
            }

            d = fe.y * boxhalfsize.x + fe.x * boxhalfsize.y;

            if (min>d || max<-d) return OUTSIDE;

            fe = abs(e1);

            // axis test x01

            p0 = e1.z * v0.y - e1.y * v0.z;
            p2 = e1.z * v2.y - e1.y * v2.z;

            min = p2;
            max = p0;

            if (p0<p2)
            {
                min = p0;
                max = p2;
            }

            d = fe.z * boxhalfsize.y + fe.y * boxhalfsize.z;

            if (min>d || max<-d) return OUTSIDE;

            // axis test y02

            p0 = -e1.z * v0.x + e1.x * v0.z;
            p2 = -e1.z * v2.x + e1.x * v2.z;

            min = p2;
            max = p0;

            if (p0<p2)
            {
                min = p0;
                max = p2;
            }

            d = fe.z * boxhalfsize.x + fe.x * boxhalfsize.z;

            if (min>d || max<-d) return OUTSIDE;

            // axis test z0

            p0 = e1.y * v0.x - e1.x * v0.y;
            p1 = e1.y * v1.x - e1.x * v1.y;

            min = p1;
            max = p0;

            if (p0<p1)
            {
                min = p0;
                max = p1;
            }

            d = fe.y* boxhalfsize.x + fe.x * boxhalfsize.y;

            if (min>d || max<-d) return OUTSIDE;

            fe = abs(e2);

            // axis test x02

            p0 = e2.z * v0.y - e2.y * v0.z;
            p1 = e2.z * v1.y - e2.y * v1.z;

            min = p1;
            max = p0;

            if (p0<p1)
            {
                min = p0;
                max = p1;
            }

            d = fe.z * boxhalfsize.y + fe.y * boxhalfsize.z;

            if (min>d || max<-d) return OUTSIDE;

            // axis test y01

            p0 = -e2.z * v0.x + e2.x * v0.z;
            p1 = -e2.z * v1.x + e2.x * v1.z;

            min = p1;
            max = p0;

            if (p0<p1)
            {
                min = p0;
                max = p1;
            }

            d = fe.z * boxhalfsize.x + fe.x * boxhalfsize.z;

            if (min>d || max<-d) return OUTSIDE;

            // axis test z12 

            p1 = e2.y * v1.x - e2.x * v1.y;
            p2 = e2.y * v2.x - e2.x * v2.y;

            min = p1;
            max = p2;

            if (p2<p1)
            {
                min = p2;
                max = p1;
            }

            d = fe.y * boxhalfsize.x + fe.x * boxhalfsize.y;

            if (min>d || max<-d) return 0;

            //  first test overlap in the {x,y,z}-directions 
            //  find min, max of the triangle each direction, 
            //  and test for overlap in 
            //  that direction -- this is equivalent to testing 
            //  a minimal AABB around 
            //  the triangle against the AABB 

            // test in X-direction 

            min = v0.x;
            max = v0.x;

            if (v1.x<min) min = v1.x;
            if (v1.x>max) max = v1.x;
            if (v2.x<min) min = v2.x;
            if (v2.x>max) max = v2.x;

            if (min>boxhalfsize.x || max<-boxhalfsize.x) return OUTSIDE;

            // test in Y-direction 

            min = v0.y;
            max = v0.y;

            if (v1.y<min) min = v1.y;
            if (v1.y>max) max = v1.y;
            if (v2.y<min) min = v2.y;
            if (v2.y>max) max = v2.y;

            if (min>boxhalfsize.y || max<-boxhalfsize.y) return OUTSIDE;

            // test in Z-direction 

            min = v0.z;
            max = v0.z;

            if (v1.z<min) min = v1.z;
            if (v1.z>max) max = v1.z;
            if (v2.z<min) min = v2.z;
            if (v2.z>max) max = v2.z;

            if (min>boxhalfsize.z || max<-boxhalfsize.z) return OUTSIDE;

            //  test if the box intersects the plane of the triangle 

            // test x

            if (normal.x>0.0f)
            {
                vmin.x = -boxhalfsize.x;
                vmax.x =  boxhalfsize.x;
            }
            else
            {
                vmin.x =  boxhalfsize.x;
                vmax.x = -boxhalfsize.x;
            }

            // test y

            if (normal.y>0.0f)
            {
                vmin.y = -boxhalfsize.y;
                vmax.y =  boxhalfsize.y;
            }
            else
            {
                vmin.y =  boxhalfsize.y;
                vmax.y = -boxhalfsize.y;
            }

            // test z

            if (normal.z>0.0f)
            {
                vmin.z = -boxhalfsize.z;
                vmax.z =  boxhalfsize.z;
            }
            else
            {
                vmin.z =  boxhalfsize.z;
                vmax.z = -boxhalfsize.z;
            }

            // test max and min 

            d = -(normal.x * v0.x + normal.y * v0.y + normal.z * v0.z);

            if (normal.x * vmin.x + normal.y * vmin.y + normal.z * vmin.z + d >  0.0f) return OUTSIDE;

            if (normal.x * vmax.x + normal.y * vmax.y + normal.z * vmax.z + d >= 0.0f) return INTERSECT;

            // box and triangle don't overlap 

            return OUTSIDE;
        }
```

Comment: This feels like a copy+paste answer without any explanation that's not even in the correct language.

Comment: I think that a good programmer understand better the code rather than a lenghty explanation, if you can't follow some code, you'd better to start thinking changin career or hobby

Comment: That's a very rude thing to say - that they shouldn't program if they can't understand your code. At some point it is no longer the reader's fault if they can't understand your code but it's your fault. Nevertheless that was not the point of my comment. I just pointed out that you do a minimal job of explaining what you're doing and then you don't even do it in the correct language, which might be important for someone that's not that familiar with C syntax. This answer should at least have 1-2 lines explaining SAT and maybe even a link for further reading.